# C++ constructor for inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I just want to check in order to inherit a constructor from the parent class is this the correct way to do it by using object composition?

and I'm getting this errors and they are all referring to my constructors.

```
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0CYtVR.o:SquareImp.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefine
d reference to `vtable for Square'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0CYtVR.o:SquareImp.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefine
d reference to `vtable for Square'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0CYtVR.o:SquareImp.cpp:(.text$_ZN6SquareD1Ev[
Square::~Square()]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for Square'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry this is my new script as I've made try rewriting them

ShapeTwoD.h

```
class ShapeTwoD
{
    protected:
        string name, warpSpace;
        bool containsWarpSpace;
        int xCord, yCord, length, breath;
    public:
        //constructor
        ShapeTwoD();
        ShapeTwoD(string, bool);
};
```

ShapeTwoD.cpp

```
ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD()
{
    string name = "";
    bool containsWarpSpace = true;
}

ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD(string ShapeName, bool warpspace)
{
    name = ShapeName;
    containsWarpSpace = true;
}
```

square.h

```
class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{
    private:
        int xVal,yVal;
        int newlength, newbreath;
        double area;

    public:
        Square();
        Square(string, bool, int, int);
};
```

square.cpp

```
Square::Square()
{
    xVal = 0;
    yVal = 0;
}

  Square::Square(string ShapeName, bool warpspace, int xval, int yval):ShapeTwoD(ShapeName, warpspace), xVal(xval), yVal(yval)
    {
    xVal = xval;
    YVal = yval;
    cout << "test test" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Square square;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? For example, you can print statements in the constructor and determine in what order they're built.

Comment: Looks good. There is a [site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in the StackExchange network for code review, it may be better suited there.

Comment: OK, it seems you've edited your question. How do you declared those classes?

Comment: Ahh, but it then isn't a question about specifics of construction order. It is a question of my code won't compile.

Comment: @MM I've already updated the question but I'm still getting the same compilation error.. why is this so?

Comment: @koi_s3ng: Put the class declaration, how do you inherited `Square` from `ShapeTwoD` class?

Comment: @MM. this is how I inherit Square from ShapeTwoD

"Class Square:public ShapeTwoD"

Comment: @koi_s3ng: It seems you somewhere used `ShapeTwoD` without constructing it. Do you have another constructor for `Square`?

Comment: @MM. Sorry but I have updated the question again, does adding a default constructor actually helps? cause it's a different error msg..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and also put `xVal` and `yVal` in the initializer list too:

```
Square::Square(string ShapeName, bool square, int xval, int yval):
      ShapeTwoD(ShapeName, square), xVal(xval), yVal(yval)
{
}
```

And construct base class for `Square()` too:

```
Square::Square() : ShapeTwoD(..., ...)
{
}
```

Comment: sorry why do I have to include "xVal(xval), yVal(yval)"?

Comment: You don't have to, your way works, but this way is standard and has good advantages specially for initializing objects.